# Can you integrate a built-in image compressor for a Wordpress theme?

Tags: php, wordpress, image, bandwidth, image-compression

I currently am customizing a Wordpress theme called Classifier (http://colorlabsproject.com/themes/classifier/), built by Colorlabs & Company. I'm running into a pretty big issue and that is the size of users uploaded images.

Our website receives 200,000+ page views a month, with 90,000-110,000 of those views being from unique IP's. The theme allows you set a maximum image size, but to ask 25,000-100,000 users to compress their photos is not practical, at all, and frankly the majority of users won't know how to do it or just won't do it.

When looking at a website like Craigslist, they allow their millions of users to upload 18 photos per listing, with zero regulation on image size. The website still operates smoothly, with no lag time, which leads me to believe they have an image compressor built into their website.

I'd like to allow my users to upload photos and have them be automatically compressed to a certain size once they submit their listing. I'm wondering if this is possible and if yes, where do I begin?

Comment: google tinypng its not cheap but you could compress using that. The re are linux compression programs as well that will give you fairly good results. But your 1st step is to resize the image - http://php.net/manual/en/book.imagick.php

Comment: Try the imsanity plugin - https://wordpress.org/plugins/imsanity/

Answer (score 0):

You can integrate this plugin : [Compress JPEG & PNG images](https://wordpress.org/plugins/tiny-compress-images/). They also have an [API](https://tinypng.com/developers) .